# Variables not getting updated in catch block inside .map()

Tags: javascript, node.js

Fellow Wizards,

i am using .map() to iterate array of Objects, after some manipulations and assigning values to defined variables i am inserting them in postgres database

```
const insertIntoDB = (jsonObj) => {
  let client = connectDB()
  let customerId = null
  let shippingName = null
  let shippingZip = null
  let firstOrder = null
  let lastOrder = null
  let isReturning = null
  let query = {
    text = `INSERT INTO ${tableFullName}(customer_id, shipping_name, shipping_zip, first_order, last_order, is_returning) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)`,
    values = []
  }
  await Promise.all( jsonObj.map((item) => {
    customerId = item.customerId
    shippingName = item.shippingName
    shippingZip = item.shippingZip
    firstOrder = item.firstOrder
    lastOrder = item.lastOrder
    isReturning = false

    if(item.orders > 1) isReturning = true

    client.query(query)
      .then(() => {
       console.log('Inserted',customerId)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
       // here customerId gets the same value where exception was thrown for the all iterations 
       // but err reports duplicate key for each customerId
       console.log(customerId, err)
      }) 
  })
})
```

while the map iterates, when an exception is thrown for duplicate entry in database, the value of customerId stays same for which the first error was thrown.

```
error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "customers_customer_id_key"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage 
  length: 242,
  name: 'error',
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '23505',
  detail: 'Key (customer_id)=(5374657068616e696520) already exists.',
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: 'public',
  table: 'customers',
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: 'customers_customer_id_key',
  file: 'nbtinsert.c',
  line: '570',
  routine: '_bt_check_unique'
} {
  text: 'INSERT INTO public.customers(customer_id, shipping_name, shipping_zip, first_order, last_order, is_returning) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)',
  values: [
    '4a756c6965204772696e', // <= CustomerId
    'Julie Grindstaff',
    "'37128",
    '8/15/19 18:44',
    '8/15/19 18:44',
    false
  ]
}
```

If you notice the CustomerId in values and in details are different.

Comment: This is an improper usage of `map()`.  Map, as an iterator, is a more distinct form of iteration that is expected to be used with *translating* an array of elements into another array of different elements.  If you are not wanting to translate all the elements, and you just need to iterate over them, then use `forEach` instead.

Comment: even with the ```forEach``` loop the problem remains there.

Comment: I do not doubt that.  I simply pointed out one code smell.

Comment: I appreciate it, i am actually wrapping it in ```Promise.all``` in my actual code so ```map()``` is kind of more suitable in what i am doing.

Comment: You should definitely move your query builder into `map`.

Comment: Thanks @EugeneObrezkov, but this seems to defy the laws of shallow cloning, doesn't it?

Comment: You have async operations with side effects. It is bad, like really bad. Your `map` function does not wait for actually added record and just spawns all of them with the same arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try to optimise your code at first and get rid of unnecessary complicated logic. Here is an overall simplification, try to adopt this one first and check if your error still persists.

```
async function insertIntoDB(jsonObj) {
  const client = await connectDB();
  const promises = jsonObj.map((item) => {
    let { customerId, shippingName, shippingZip, firstOrder, lastOrder } = item;
    let isReturning = false
    let query = {
      text: `INSERT INTO ${tableFullName}(customer_id, shipping_name, shipping_zip, first_order, last_order, is_returning) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)`,
      values: []
    }

    if (item.orders > 1) isReturning = true

    return client.query(query);
  })

  return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

I really believe, that your problem is because of race conditions, that you can resolve by not using async operations without actually awaiting them, moreover async operations with side effects.

**UPD**: as @slebetman pointed out the problem was with the `query` variable that was out of `map` scope. Hence, the query was the same every iteration. By moving `query` into iteration loop the problem was fixed, according to the latest comment from author.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene, I am definitely doing this in my actual code.

Comment: According to OP, you are definitely not doing this.

Comment: Update the OP with your code you actually running, do not add it as a comment, thanks

Comment: I've updated the code to match my actual code. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The problem is not the awaiting. The problem (which you solve BTW) is that the variable  `query` is shared in all the loops. So that the `map()` loops through each time running the same query - inserting the same data. Of course that will obviously lead to duplicate id

Comment: Thanks @slebetman, i was looking through a different perspective but yes moving the query inside solved the problem.